# HBase truncate table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

If I will truncate table from HBase, then
1) Does it deletes data from underlying HDFS system also or it just marks data with deletion marker ? 
2) How can I make sure/verify that data is also deleted from underlying HDFS system ?

Comment: By "deleted from the underlying HDFS", do you mean deleted from disk?  Or just removed from the HDFS file table in the NameNode?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, I just want to make sure I answer correctly- by deleted from disk do you mean deleted from the native file system or overwritten with zeroes?  I.e. what security threat are you trying to mitigate- someone with read access to the drive reading the data, or someone walking off with a drive and reading the data later at their leisure?

Comment: I mean data should be deleted from disk, so it should be deleted from native file system also. Here I want to ensure nobody can read/reproduce data again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no way to ensure that HBase table data is completely erased from the underlying filesystem.  The HBase table's files may be deleted from HDFS, but that still just means that they are moved to the trash folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hbase tombstones data when they are deleted from tables, so scanning/getting rows does not return them and they cannot be read.
When a Major compaction is run on the table all the tombstoned data is deleted from Hbase and HDFS (native fileSystem) and frees up disk.

Comment: Tombstoning doesn't apply when a table is truncated.  A truncate is a delete/recreate of the table, meaning that new HDFS files are created for the table.

Comment: oh right, I overlooked the truncate part, my answer was for row deletion, thanks for correcting.